# Return a Thymeleaf view as just a string in a Spring MVC Controller

Tags: spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I have a nice little Spring 4 MVC site going with Thymeleaf 3Beta. It works great to render HTML to the browser, but there's a case where I need to render the HTML into just a string before loosing control of the controller method.

So what I am asking, how do call the Thymeleaf bean up, make it run a view and return it to me as just a string that I can then send to something else?

Is this even possible?

Comment: See http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/articles/springmail.html

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in fateddy link, you just need to inject the template engine in your controller

`@Autowired
private TemplateEngine templateEngine;`

and call

`String str = templateEngine.process(templateName, context);`

to render the template to a String.

All variables referenced in your template should be included in the context object with `ctx.setVariable`, just as you would normally do with a `Model` or `ModelAndView` object.